# Check if list is ascending by 1 in python

Tags: python

I want to check if my given list is ascending by 1 or not

so:

`[1,2,3,4] = True
[1,3,4,5] = False`

and if possible I want to do it with some python specific functions - so not looping it with a for if combination but something like all(... for values in list)

I hope this is clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if consecutive elements of array are evenly spaced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741961/how-to-check-if-consecutive-elements-of-array-are-evenly-spaced)

Comment: @kaya3 Not exactly a duplicate, even though this is a special case of the other question. IMO, someone who has this specific question shouldn't be forced to read the general one

Comment: Alright, I will translate my answer to a simplified form here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```py
def has_stepsize_one(it):
    return all(x2 - x1 == 1 for x1, x2 in zip(it[:-1], it[1:]))
```

```py
>>> has_stepsize_one([1,2,3,4])
True

>>> has_stepsize_one([1,3,4,5])
False
```

This should work with any collection, not just lists.

Keep in mind that this returns `True` for collections with less than two elements:

```py
>>> has_stepsize_one([1])
True

>>> has_stepsize_one([])
True
```

If you don't want that, you'll have to check the length of the iterator.

For generic iterators that don't support `getitem`, comparing to `itertools.count` is probably the best way to do it (similar to [kaya3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58861407/5661194)):

```py
import itertools

def has_stepsize_one(it):
    it = iter(it)
    try:
        first = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return True

    return all(x == y for x, y in zip(it, itertools.count(first + 1)))
```

```py
>>> has_stepsize_one((i for i in range(10)))
True
```

Comment: `itertools.islice` is a better solution even for lists, since regular list slicing constructs a new list in memory.

Comment: It didn't work on one-shot iterators though. I replaced it with `itertools.count`, now it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Why not compare it to the `range`

```
l == list(range(l[0], l[-1] + 1))
```

Comment: 12345 was just an example - can be 123 124 125

Comment: But those do not all have step size one - so they are false in the last two cases and true  in the first case

Comment: ? sure 123 is the starting number +1 = 124 +1 =125

Comment: Hahaha I thought you meant 3 separate lists of 1,2,3, 1,2,4, and 1,2,5. Run the code in this case - `l  = [123, 124, 125]` it gives True - is this not what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Compare entire list:

```py
if my_list == list(range(my_list[0], my_list[0] + len(my_list)))
    # do things
```

Or compare in the list itself with enumerate:

```py
if all(entry - 1 == my_list[i-1] or i == 0 for i, entry in enumerate(my_list))
```

Where the `i == 0` checks for the first iteration, which is always true, since a naive for-loop will have len(my_list) iteration while we only do len(my_list) - 1 comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a single function but you could use this:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
print(lst == list(range(lst[0],lst[-1]+1,1)))
True

lst = [1,3,4,5]
print(lst == list(range(lst[0],lst[-1]+1,1)))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other answers work by creating a new list, which takes O(n) time and O(n) auxiliary space. It's possible to do this with O(1) auxiliary space using `all`, `range` and `zip`. This solution also short-circuits, so it takes O(1) time in the best case.

```py
def is_ascending(lst):
    # special case: an empty list is ascending
    if not lst:
        return True

    start = lst[0]
    end = start + len(lst)
    # general case: an ascending list equals a range
    return all( x == y for x, y in zip(lst, range(start, end)) )
```

Tests:

```py
>>> is_ascending([1, 2, 3, 4])
True
>>> is_ascending([1, 3, 4, 5])
False
>>> is_ascending([23])
True
```

Comment: Not quite true; my last solution has the same properties.