# How to get the spacing of an evenly spaced numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, intervals, spacing

I have a numpy array `array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`, how do I get its spacing which is 1?

Comment: Just subtract a pair of elements, or `np.diff` for all differences.

Comment: if `a` is the array, then `all(np.diff(a)==np.diff(a)[0])`  will give you `True`. That tells you they are evenly spaced

Comment: I also found this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741961/how-to-check-if-consecutive-elements-of-array-are-evenly-spaced

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if consecutive elements of array are evenly spaced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741961/how-to-check-if-consecutive-elements-of-array-are-evenly-spaced)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that *Numpy* array has not any attribute like **spacing**.

But if you know that the distances between all elements are the same,
it is enough to compute the distance between any pair of consecutive
elements, e.g.:

```
dist = arr[1] - arr[0]
```

In your case it is just *1*.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is equally spaced and sorted perfectly:

```
arr=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
np.diff(arr)
# output: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

If your array has some repeated values in random order:

```
arr=np.array([9, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
np.diff(np.unique(arr))
# output: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```