# Python numpy array filter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter

I got the following  [numpy array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0djNP.png) named 'data'. It consists of 15118 rows and 2 columns. The first column mostly consist of 0.01 steps, but sometimes there is a step in between (shown in red) which I would like to remove/filter out.

I achieved this with the following code:

```
# Create array [0, 0.01 .... 140], rounded 2 decimals to prevent floating point error
b = np.round(np.arange(0,140.01,0.01),2)

# New empty data array
new_data = np.empty(shape=[0, 2])

# Loop over values to remove/filter out data
for x in b:
    Index = np.where(x == data[:,0])[0][0]
    new_data = np.vstack([new_data,data[Index]])
```

I feel like this code is far from optimal and I was wondering if anyone knows a faster/better way of achieving this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if consecutive elements of array are evenly spaced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741961/how-to-check-if-consecutive-elements-of-array-are-evenly-spaced)

Comment: Is this question regarding the rounding error? I would probably do ```b = np.arange(0, 141, dtype=np.float32) / 100```

Comment: Using rounding to ensure equality is really unsafe unless both `data[:,0]` and `b` are rounded using a IEEE-754 compliant method. Using a strict floating-point equality is generally a bad idea. Use intervals or epsilon-based checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using pandas for resampling, you can probably achieve the same result in pure numpy but there are a number of floating point and rounding error pitfalls you are going to face, maybe it's better to let a trusted library do the work for you.

Let's say `arr` is your data array and assume your index to be in fractions of seconds. You can convert your array to a dataframe with a timedelta index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arr[:,1], index=arr[:,0])
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit="s")
```

Than resampling it's pretty easy, `10ms` is the frequency you want, `first()` should give you the expected result dropping everything but the records at `10ms` ticks, but feel free to experiment with other functions

```
df = df.resample("10ms").first()
```

Eventually you could get back to your array with something like:

```
np.vstack([pd.to_numeric(df.index, downcast="float").values / 1e9,
           df.values.squeeze()]).T
```